# Badges with long names overflow on the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

I just saw on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) user's profile that long badge names (`google-chrome-extension`) flow out the side of the badge:

[image]

Can we either add more space for those long-name badges or hide the overflow (`overflow: hidden;`) in the CSS?

Comment: Cross-site report on MSO: [Overflow on badges in profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406183/4642212).

Comment: @SebastianSimon whoops, you're right.  It does happen elsewhere on the network, though.

Comment: @Justin It's on the "Profile" tab, not the "Activity" one, under Badges:  https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom?tab=profile

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this bug posted yesterday: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368273/718314

Comment: @KylePollard Since it's for the new UI, then yeah, I agree.  Otherwise I'd say it's the other way round ;)

Comment: @Ollie Oh uh whoops, totally missed that this is older.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug also appeared in the new badge UI and has been fixed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368533/718314

[image: A screenshot of TheLethalCarrot's gold badges on their user profile where the badge marvel-cinematic-universe has been truncated to marvel-cinematic-univ…]