# Badge text overflows with long tags in user profile

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page

I found this *[android-jetpack-compose](/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose)* in the rarest badge section of [this profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208273/ryan-m):

[image]

**Badge tag consist of `a` tag**

I debugged and found that the `max-width: 150px;` option produced the error - the code is as below

```
 .profile-badges .badge-tag{
    max-width: 150px;
 }
```

Comment: there must be a dupe for this

Comment: @Luuklag Yes: [Badges with long names overflow on the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362466/badges-with-long-names-overflow-on-the-profile-page)

Comment: I'm famous!  Enshrined as an example of a bug ;-)