# The new profile page badge UI cuts off on long tag names

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

If you go to [my profile](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot?tab=profile) on SFF you'll see the following*:

[image]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Notice that the badge background for the gold tag badge [marvel-cinematic-universe] crops off before the end of the text. Presumably there's a max size or something for the background and so it's not sizing correctly on longer tag names.

I'm seeing this on Windows 10 and Chrome 92.

---

<sub>*Ignore the freehand red circle, I'm recycling a screenshot.</sub>

Comment: Seems that the tag in question is *just* at the **old** maximum length (25 characters); but that was increased to [35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13270/616624) - so there's potential for more severe cut-off issues.

Comment: Similar report for the old UI: [Badges with long names overflow on the profile page](/q/362466/289905).

Comment: Related: *[Some changes to the profile while we make it responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368285)* (2021-08-05)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this problem - really long badge names will now use ellipses:

[image: A screenshot of TheLethalCarrot's gold badges on their user profile where the badge marvel-cinematic-universe has been truncated to marvel-cinematic-univ…]

Using ellipses here isn't necessarily the best design, so we might iterate on this again as we continue work on [making our user profiles more responsive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368285/718314).

(Great work on a [marvel-cinematic-universe](/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) gold tag badge by the way! Do your gold tag badges come with some kind of Stack Exchange Infinity Gauntlet?)

Comment: Just get Mjolnir!